# Another verb for "speaks to"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, verbs, formality

I often hear the phrase 'speak to' used as a verb. For example, "This event *speaks to* the need for good communication" or "Samantha, can you please *speak to* these dot points?"

It seems appropriate for a casual or colloquial scenario. The term 'address' can also be used but I feel this often implies the original material was a problem or issue. Whereas, 'Speaks to' can be used to offer a reflection or explanation of the original material.

Is there a more formal or professional verb that could also be used in this instance?

Comment: *Explain* or *explains* ?

Comment: My immediate interpretation of *this event speaks to the need*… was *this event is evidence for the need*…

Answer (score 2):

This event addresses the need for good communication.

This event focuses on the need for good communication.

Samantha, can you respond to these dot points?

Answer (score 2):

**I believe the answer to be "no". I do not think there is a "more formal or professional verb" that you might use, except possibly *to address***. Indeed I fail to see what is not formal or professional about ***speak to*** used in this way.

It is recognised in the OED as sense 5, of the second meaning of *speak* meaning to *address words or discourse*, as opposed to *uttering or pronouncing words*.

As you will see its first reference is from 1610.

> 5. To treat of or deal with, to discuss or comment on, (a subject) in speech or writing.
>
> 1610   J. Dove Advt. Seminaries 42,   I desire them therefore..to
>   speake to these foure points.
>
> 1637   P. Heylyn Briefe Answer Burton 78   For your charges,..I meane
>   to take them..in order, and speake as briefely to them, as you would
>   desire.
>
> 1662   E. Stillingfleet Origines Sacræ ii. vi. §4   Though it be a
>   subject little spoken to either by Jewish or Christian Writers.
>
> 1706   G. Stanhope Paraphr. Epist. & Gospels III. 555   Part of this
>   Scripture hath already been spoken to.
>
> 1735   Swift Let. to Middleton in Wks. IV. 186   A Lawyer who speaks
>   to a Cause, when the Matter hath been almost exhausted by those who
>   spoke before.
>
> 1778   Earl of Malmesbury Diaries & Corr. I. 166   Unprepared as he
>   was for such a proposition, he could not, he said, off-hand, speak to
>   it accurately.
>
> 1869   Daily News 28 Apr.   The report..was spoken to by the Most Rev.
>   Chairman..and the Bishop of Derry.
>
> 1880   Daily News 19 Mar. 2/3,   I wish to call your
>   attention..to..that allegation, and I shall endeavour to speak to it.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion that 'speaks to' is adequately formal.

Answer (score 0):

'Attests to' or 'resonates with' are other options. I find that students overuse 'speaks to' for want of a better phrase.

Comment: In many contexts, _underscores_ works well as an alternative, too.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, such as your first example, "demonstrates" or "illustrates" would work:

> This event demonstrates the need for good communication.
>
> This event illustrates the need for good communication.

Your second example is using the term in somewhat of a different sense. There, I might replace it with "address" or "respond to", such as:

> Samantha, can you please address these dot points?
>
> Samantha, can you please respond to these dot points?

Also, I agree with user WS2 that there is nothing informal or inappropriate about the use of "speaks to".